# using "Out.print" for special characters

Tags: javascript

when I use out.print with for a string which includes <>, it removes the part inside the bracket. what do I do to get it printed?

thanks
Nasrin

Comment: Can you post some example code for us to work with please?

Comment: I assume this code runs in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sarpyjr.

so I found my answer by doing so:

String = String.replaceAll("<","&lt");

this will replace non printable character > with &lt which works in html. 
I did the same for >, replaced it with &gt.

thanks